# Display Image from Windows Folder in Crystal Reports 8.5 or 9

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I am Storing unique Picture name in database.
In Picture folder same name is applying for picture also.
I need to load picture from the picture folder with respect to the name stored in database.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Go into **Format Graphic**
2. Go to the **Picture** tab
3. Go into the **Graphic Location** custom formula
4. Enter your database field.